# perl inline::C failed to map segment from shared object in openmediavault shared folder, in linux itself or in windows by SAMBA

Tags: c, perl, inline

I got an old PC and installed a openmediavault in it. Then shared its RAID as shared folder, then mapping this folder to windows via SAMBA. I could run Steam game in this shared folder in windows.

I wrote a perl script to demo the inline::C, its a very little script.

```perl
use 5.24.0;
use warnings;
use Inline C=><<'_C_CODE_';

void say_something(){
    printf("Y!");
}

_C_CODE_

say_something();
```

Then if I put this perl script file in the shared folder, perl will fail to complie this script. In **windows**, perl reports "*fail to load 'xxx\xxx.dll*', while in **linux**, perl reports "*failed to map segment from shared object at /xx/xx/xx.so*".

But, if I copy this script to local disk of windows or none-shared folder in linux, I could compile it without any error or warning.

This issue total confused me, especially why it failed in windows.

PS: I tried
1. chmod +x to the folder and the _Inline/xx/xx/xxx.so, failed.
2. access this folder via /srv/dev-disk-by-label-NAS01/xxx/, not /sharedfolders/xxx/, failed.
3. sudo perl xxx.pl, failed

Comment: I searched the source of [`Inline`](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/I/IN/INGY/Inline-0.86.tar.gz), [`Inline::C`](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/T/TI/TINITA/Inline-C-0.81.tar.gz) and [`DynaLoader`](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/tree/blead/ext/DynaLoader) for the text *"failed to map segment from shared object"*  but there where no matches, so it seems the error message is not produced by any Perl module. So my guess would be that it comes from a C library function called from DynaLoader

Comment: On my web host, files located in /tmp can't be executed because of restriction on the volume (`noexec`). Security modules (e.g. SELinux) can probably impose such restrictions as well. Maybe that's why you can't?